# LocalForage, images and Blobs

Tags: javascript, promise, local-storage, blob, localforage

I'm a bit confused about the use of LocalForage.
I just want to save and retrieve an image from LocalForage, here is how I do.

```
function preload() {

    localforage.setDriver(localforage.LOCALSTORAGE).then(function() {

        lcl_images[0] = new Object();
        lcl_images[0].key = 'lclstorage_1';
        lcl_images[0].value = 'http://www.superga.com/tcnimg/S/02/S009TE0/XBS009TE0___949______.jpg';

        lcl_images[1] = new Object();
        lcl_images[1].key = 'lclstorage_2';
        lcl_images[1].value = 'https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/max_1200/2150fb35419617.56f6327b44e47.gif';

        for (var i = lcl_images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            var valore = lcl_images[i].value;
            localforage.setItem(lcl_images[i].key, lcl_images[i].value, function() {
                console.log('Saved: ' + valore);
            });
        }
    });
}

function use_preloaded_image() {

    for (var i = lcl_images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        var key = lcl_images[i].key;
        localforage.getItem(lcl_images[i].key, function(err, readValue) {
            console.log('Read: ', readValue);
            document.getElementById(key).src = readValue;
        });
    }
}
```

The point is, I don't know if it is the right method to use images: **I store them as strings**, localForage should use `parse` and `stringify`.
**This example is working fine** (when I go offline, I refresh the page, images in localstorage are vsible), but I see someone using Image objects or Blobs (I neve heard about that, and an instant search hasn't told me much about that).
other do an XHR request to download the image, then they save it.

I can think about the use of XHR request for the need of checking whether the image has been downloaded. Is this right?

Secondly: someone says that storing with blobs is better. Why?

Please help me, thanks.

**EDIT (Multiple Promises)**

When I retrieve images I must bind each of them to an `<img>`. But I don't know how to do it, with promises. Because when using `Promise.all()` I can't use a `for` loop (so no index to bind images src with images id).

```
var promises = [];

for (var i = lcl_images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    promises.push(localforage.getItem(lcl_images[i].key));
}

Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

for (var i = lcl_images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    document.getElementById(lcl_images[i].key).src = value;
}



Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then(function(value) {
        console.log(value);
        document.getElementById(lcl_images[i].key).src = value;
        // I can't get the index i, no way to set <img> src for id attribute
    }) 
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

**FIX** *Promise.all().then()*

```
Promise
.all(promises)
.then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
    for (var i = lcl_images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        document.getElementById(lcl_images[i].key).src = value[i];
    };
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blobs are better because IndexedDB can optimize their storage on disk. In essence it stores them directly as file handles. (In cases where Blobs aren't supported or IDB isn't supported, LocalForage will convert to base64.)

To download an image as a Blob, the easiest way is to use a fetch polyfill or the `fetch()` API and use `response.blob()` (see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob)). Another way is to use XMLHttpRequest and do `xhr.responseType = 'blob`. Example:

```
fetch('http://example.com/myimage.gif').then(function (response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function (blob) {
  console.log("yay I have a blob", blob);
}).catch(console.log.bind(console))
```

Also another thing you should know is that it looks like you are making a classic Promise mistake in your code, which is to do multiple Promises within a `forEach()` loop. You probably would rather do `Promise.all()`. Please read [We have a problem with promises](https://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) for more details.

For working with Blobs, you can check out [blob-util](https://github.com/nolanlawson/blob-util), which has a tutorial, or you can read [the PouchDB guide to attachments](http://pouchdb.com/guides/attachments). (PouchDB uses Blobs similarly to LocalForage, so the advice is similar.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped a lot. But I'm in trouble with promise.all. Since I can't run a loop, I don't know how to bind the image id (stored in key) with the img src (stored in value).

Comment: Promise.all gives you a promise for an array. In your code you seem to assume `value` is a single thing, not an array.

Comment: I was developing while you replied, i'm gonna edit this. So, just to point out  a question: if I want to wait until all images have been download, I should add like `var is_all_stored=false` and `promise.then(value){ is_all_stored=true;}`. By this way I can go offline when it is all stored, is it right?

Comment: a question about the polyfill: it should replicate the behavior of xhr, available on all versions of browsers.. but looking at https://github.com/github/fetch#browser-support it is supported only by the latest version of major browsers, and IE 10+. Really?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch reports `fetch` natively supported by FF 39, Chrome 42.

Comment: Hi, there are lots of fetch() polyfills out there; hopefully you can find one that supports the browsers you want. Else you can just use XMLHttpRequest like normal and wrap it in a promise, or use jQuery 3.0 which has native support for Promises and `$.ajax()` to do that.